# accessing github through http protocol without using the git client

Tags: git, github, wget

I've been trying to learn more about the git internals, specifically the protocol. I know how to use the git client, but I want to try playing with the git protocol without it in order to learn more. When I tried running

```
wget https://github.com/git/git.git/info/refs
```

or visiting the url in a browser I get a 403 forbidden. Why do I need to authenticate when I am just trying to read the file? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Seeing your comment on the below answer, I suggest you check out the "[Git - Transfer Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols)" section of the Git Pro book.

Comment: yes, I have looked at that page - so how do I do all the GET commands listed on it without using the git client?

Comment: Check out "[9 uses for cURL worth knowing](https://httpkit.com/resources/HTTP-from-the-Command-Line/)", that's probably the easiest way to mimic HTTP requests from the command line with enough flexibility for you to see all the gory details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That URL would be used with git's dumb HTTP method which [github has disabled](https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days). You'd need to use a repository hosted elsewhere to work with that. With github you need to use the newer smart HTTP transport.

Comment: thanks! do you know where to find a specification of the smart http protocol?

Comment: I think the closest to a specification would be the [git http-backend man page][https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html]. It's really just a small wrapper around the same protocol used for ssh:// and git:// transports. Besides reading the source, your best bet might be to use wireshark to snoop on the traffic to a repository served over http:// rather than https:// (so someplace other than github).